# Can't connect to server, others can

Tags: internet, connection, ping, subnet

I've set up a Webserver(port 80) and a Minecraft server. Me and my friends play on this server regularly and haven't had any problems connecting before this.

Now, one friend complains about not being able to connect. In order to debug this I made him connect to my webserver(different computer, same IP), but he says he can't.
Pinging doesn't work either.

Other friends however, have no difficulty connecting, so it's not a router issue(right?)
In order to be sure, we both did a system reset on both our routers/modems, still nothing.

I did some research on why this could be, and some say that being on the same subnet results in this kind of behavior. How can i test this?

To sum up:
At first, everybody can connect.
Then out of nowhere, A can't ping B, B can't ping A. But C,D, etc. can ping A and B just fine.

What can I do to fix this?

**Edit**: We are connected over the internet.

**Edit 2**: Traceroute
$ traceroute 80.56.241.61
traceroute to 80.56.241.61 (80.56.241.61), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.15.141.1 (10.15.141.1)  10.534 ms  9.016 ms  8.072 ms
 2  p3129.net.upc.nl (212.142.3.129)  8.804 ms  9.535 ms  9.301 ms
 3  nl-ams05a-rd2-ae-30-2368.aorta.net (84.116.244.73)  11.016 ms  11.831 ms  27.244 ms
 4  84.116.244.66 (84.116.244.66)  12.686 ms  13.742 ms  11.674 ms
 5  84.116.135.30 (84.116.135.30)  11.933 ms  12.267 ms  12.614 ms
 6  p60030.net.upc.nl (212.142.60.30)  13.194 ms  12.476 ms  10.680 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *

**Edit 3**: Called UPC
Fed up, I called UPC again. They told me everything was fine and that it's most likely my server or my router's problem. Thing is, I know for sure it isn't since I reset them both. He did admin however, that it could be a subnet problem but they can't do much about that other than wait until I get a new IP.

Anybody got **ANY** ideas that don't just mean: wait?

**Edit 4**: UPC caved, they're investigating it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your friends are connecting over the public internet then try looking at the output of [tracert](http://www.computerhope.com/tracert.htm) (windows) or [traceroute](http://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) (unix) too see where the connection is being blocked if your IP address is 1.2.3.4 then

```
tracert 1.2.3.4
```

or

```
traceroute 1.2.3.4
```

If you are all connected to the same LAN then check that the IP addresses are all in the same block and then netmask for your friends computer is the same as everyone else's.

Comment: It seems it's blocked at UPC(my internet provider) but they say it's nothing on their end. Anything else I could do?

Comment: Is the friend with issues on the same ISP as you? My ISP once had some issues routing traffic between its own customers.

Comment: Yeah he has the same ISP as me.